# How to get last five consecutive values in pandas data frame row?

Tags: python, pandas, row

If I have Pandas Data Frame like this:

```
0     1 5 7 3   7 1 9   2 NaN 4 3 NaN 3 2

1     1 3 2 8   4 2 NaN 2 NaN 3 1 0   4 1

2     1 5 1 NaN 7 3 2   1 3   5 0 NaN 2 1

3     1 4 5 3   1 2 NaN 1 3   1 2 NaN 2 1
```

How can I find the last five consecutive values in each row? Like this below:

```
3 7 1 9 2

3 1 0 4 1

2 1 3 5 0

4 5 3 1 2
```

Comment: use location indexing df.iloc[:,-5:]

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what he is after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df.T.apply(lambda x:  x[x.groupby(x.isnull().cumsum()).transform('count')>4].dropna().tail(5).values).T

     0    1    2    3    4
0  3.0  7.0  1.0  9.0  2.0
1  3.0  1.0  0.0  4.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0  3.0  5.0  0.0
3  4.0  5.0  3.0  1.0  2.0
```

Or

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.groupby(x.isnull().cumsum()).transform('count')>4].dropna().tail(5).values), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  3.0  7.0  1.0  9.0  2.0
1  3.0  1.0  0.0  4.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0  3.0  5.0  0.0
3  4.0  5.0  3.0  1.0  2.0
```

Comment: This answer gave me a much better understanding of `transform()` in conjunction with `cumsum()`, much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much!